# Add a new layer to an existing model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-layer

Is it possible to add a new layer to an existing model? Consider the following model.

```py
model = Sequential([
    Resizing(...),
    Dense(...),
    Dense(...),
    Dense(...),
])
```

What I'm expecting is to add a new augmentation preprocessing layer after the initial Resizing layer.

```py
data_augmentation = Sequential([
    RandomZoom(...),
])

model2 = clone_model(model)
model2.layers.insert(1, data_augmentation)
```

Though insert function is successful I don't see the new layer in the `model2`. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492255/how-to-replace-or-insert-intermediate-layer-in-keras-model

The layers attribute is a list, so that must be why you can call .insert, but I guess there is nothing under the hood to perform the actions needed to actually build a new model from this call.